# kotlin recycleradapter bindviewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

We have a RecylerAdapter that has a onClickListener for a RelativeLayout that contains a ImageView. When the view is clicked the data is transferred to another activity for editing this works great. The problem we are having is when the ImageView is clicked on in the corresponding Activity just before navigating to the  new Activity the id replaces the text to be edited. Our question is how to get the id without the process replacing flashing the id? Our Inflated view XML and RecyclerAdapter code posted below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/click"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="370dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
class PersonRecyclerAdapter(contactList: List<Contact>, internal var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

internal var contactList: List<Contact> = ArrayList()
init { this.contactList = contactList }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_single_card,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return contactList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val items = contactList[position]
    holder.item.text = items.name

    holder.click.setOnClickListener {

        val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        holder.item.text = items.id.toString()
        i.putExtra("Mode", "E")
        i.putExtra("MainActId",items.id)
        i.putExtra("ET",items.name)
        i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding things, but let me give it a shot.  Comment if I am confused.

So you want to have a recyclerview with a list of items.  Each item has an edit button and you would like this to launch a new activity that allows the user to edit that item's name.  Then you would like to return to the previous activity and update the list.

If this is correct, you'll need to make a couple of changes.  First, in your on click listener, you are manually setting the item's text field to the item's id.

```
holder.item.text = items.id.toString();
```

There doesn't seem to be any good reason to do this.  I would recommend removing it.

Second, you'll want to start the edit activity for a result.  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result 
When you get the OnActivityResult callback in your list activity, you can get the id of the item and the new name from the bundle.  You'll then go into your list and find the item with that id, change the name to the new name, and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  This will tell your adapter that its data has changed and it should re-populate the list with new data.

Comment: Because I use the same button to call insert or update in the DBHelper my small brain overthought the idea that we needed to get the Int id. I am guessing that the id made the trip over because it is in the ArrayList associated with the data Model. Binding and RecyclerAdapter configurations seem to be able to created various ways So we deleted the id to String and life is great Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the ID in the arraylist will stay around in the list activity (as long as the activity and it's locals are not destroyed.  Then it would need to fetch it from the data model).  And the edit activity gets it from the bundle that you pass to it.  Glad it's working!